# Pandas Dataframe: How to get the cell instead of is value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a task to compare two dataframe with same columns name but different size, we can call it previous and current. I am trying to get the difference between (previous and current) in the Quantity and Booked Columns and highlight it as yellow. The common key between the two dataframe would be the 'SN' columns

I have coded out the following

```
    for idx, rows in df_n.iterrows():
        if rows["Quantity"] == rows['Available'] +  rows['Booked']:
           continue
        else:
           rows["Quantity"] = rows["Quantity"] - rows['Available'] - rows['Booked']
           df_n.loc[idx, 'Quantity'].style.applymap('background-color: yellow')
           # pdb.set_trace()
           if (df_o['Booked'][df_o['SN'] == rows["SN"]] != rows['Booked']).bool():
                df_n.loc[idx, 'Booked'].style.apply('background-color: yellow')
```

I realise I have a few problems here and need some help

- df_n.loc[idx, 'Quantity'] returns value instead of a dataframe type. How can I get a dataframe from one cell. Do I have to pd.DataFrame(data=df_n.loc[idx, 'Quantity'], index=idx, columns ='Quantity'). Will this create a copy or will update the reference?
- How do I compare the SN of both dataframe, looking for a better way to compare. One thing I could think of is to use set index for both dataframe and when finished using them, reset them back?

My dataframe:

Previous dataframe
[image: df_o previous dataframe]

Current Dataframe
[image: df_n new dataframe]

Answer (score 1):

> df_n.loc[idx, 'Quantity'] returns value instead of a dataframe type.
>   How can I get a dataframe from one cell. Do I have to
>   pd.DataFrame(data=df_n.loc[idx, 'Quantity'], index=idx, columns
>   ='Quantity'). Will this create a copy or will update the reference?

To create a DataFrame from one cell you can try: `df_n.loc[idx, ['Quantity']].to_frame().T`

> How do I compare the SN of both dataframe, looking for a better way to
>   compare. One thing I could think of is to use set index for both
>   dataframe and when finished using them, reset them back?

You can use `df_n.merge(df_o, on='S/N')` to merge dataframes and 'compare' columns.